# Is "The pond is deep and looks black" a parallel structure?

Tags: sentence-construction

I wonder if I need to change it to *"The pond is deep and **it** looks black."*

Is the original sentence fine?

Can someone help? I still haven’t got any clue yet

Answer (score 1):

Comparing

1. The pond is deep and looks black.
2. The pond is deep, and it looks black.

In 1, there's a parallelism in that both *is* and *looks* are linking verbs connecting predicate adjectives to *pond*. You might use that structure if there were some esthetic reason to, for example, for the whole phrase to be parallel to another phrase.

But, to me, it doesn't sound nearly as good as 2, the sentence with *it*.

Being parallel isn't all or nothing, and it isn't always desirable.

Comment: alright thanks, I realised that later in the evening that is and looks are both copular; but if I want to use 'and', is the comma obligatory?

Comment: It's not obligatory in a short compound sentence. The text at this link https://tinyurl.com/37zn9zkb  says "However, sometimes when the two independent clauses are short, the comma is omitted in creative writing as a matter of style and rhythm:
        The rain beat down and the wind howled."

Comment: great!! that's pretty helpful; but I meant if I want to use 'it', (I don't know what I typed 'and'), as in your sentence 2, is the comma necessary? Maybe not? For me, if there's a comma, the sentence reads, "slower?" It's just how I feel tho, what do you say?

Comment: It's purely a stylistic choice, but to me, without the comma, it's very matter-of-fact. With the comma, it does read a little slower, and with a little more feeling.

Comment: I kinda feel the same. Thanks for your replies Jack, thank you so much, now I'm quite clear about this.